# How to set automatic file name creator according to current time?

Tags: java, time, recorder

I am creating a recorder application in java. I want to set the file names according to the current time. In an android application I have seen it like

```
import android.text.format.Time;

public CallRecorder(String filename,int sample_rate)
    {
        if (filename == null)
        {
            Time t = new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            filename = t.format2445(); // Create filename from current date.
        }
```

In java what package should I use? or how to do that?

Comment: What platform is your Recorder written for?

Comment: What do mean by platform? I use windows and the app is targeted to be a desktop app.

Comment: Ok, i was a bit confused, that you give a working variant ... that does not work for you .. so i asked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is one possiblility, though I'd use the [`currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

Comment: Yes, create a Date-Object und use a formatting that matches your needs.